# Wordpress not working after migrating via SFTP

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, migration

I have moved my Wordpress files to another server via SFPT, and I have uploaded Database manually. I can enter the Dashboard and all other features except Posts, when I try to add a new post the errors below are triggered:

[image]

Comment: Is this new server the exact same domain as the old?

Comment: It's a new domain, I have updated the domain in the options table

Comment: You should also perform a find-and-replace in the database, but you need to take care of serialized data. For our sites we use [WP-CLI](https://wp-cli.org/) with a command similar to `wp search-replace "https://old.example.com" "https://new.example.com" --recurse-objects --all-tables --dry-run`. The trailing slash in the URLs shouldn't be used, and you should be absolutely certain of the protocol for the replacement. The previous command doesn't actually do anything unless you remove the `--dry-run` parameter.

Comment: I ran this command and it made the replacements successfully, but didn't solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress has a guide for this types of issues

https://wordpress.org/support/topic-tag/white-screen-of-death/

Do try updating your permalink setting from wp-admin, and give a try.
or possibility that your DB was not fully migrated to the new host.

Comment: I tried updating the permalinks but didn't work

Comment: was the DB migration complete ?

Comment: Yes, it was complete, everything shows correctly on page. The issue is on the Dashboard where I can not add new Posts or Pages.